# Highcharts with coffeescript

Tags: highcharts, coffeescript

I my application i need to integrate highcharts with coffescript.
 Please guide how to start with this. Is it customizable?. Because I need to integrate some links and buttons below the chart.

Comment: Your question is very vague please provide some code and what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

All you really need to do is take a javascript sample and use js2coffee.org to convert it to coffeescript.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rf8AS/

```
$ ->
  $("#container").highcharts
    title:
      text: "Monthly Average Temperature"
      x: -20 #center

    subtitle:
      text: "Source: WorldClimate.com"
      x: -20

    xAxis:
      categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    yAxis:
      title:
        text: "Temperature (°C)"

      plotLines: [
        value: 0
        width: 1
        color: "#808080"
      ]

    tooltip:
      valueSuffix: "°C"

    legend:
      layout: "vertical"
      align: "right"
      verticalAlign: "middle"
      borderWidth: 0

    series: [
      name: "Tokyo"
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    ,
      name: "New York"
      data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    ,
      name: "Berlin"
      data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    ,
      name: "London"
      data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    ]
```

From there, you'll need to decide how you want to serve the coffeescript to the browser. I use `grunt`, `grunt-contrib-coffee` and `grunt-contrib-watch` to build the javascript on the server side. Another option is connect-assets; if you want a sample app that uses connect-assets, angular and node.js check out Hoverbear's sample app: https://github.com/Hoverbear/Angular-Coffee-Express.

Comment: Hi jcollum, Thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: @user2886647 make sure to mark as answer if it helped and answered your question